# How to draw an annulus with four different color in ppt

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to draw a annulus with 4 different colors (in each quarter). The way I can think is to draw four quarter block arcs. But it's difficult to draw the block arc exactly quarterly. I am wondering if there is any better way.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your desired shape looks something like this.

[image]

One quick way to do this is to use PowerPoint's built-in SmartArt as a shortcut.

1. Insert this SmartArt shape:

   [image]
2. Delete the outer boxes, and ungroup the image (before and after shown here).

   [image]
3. Ungroup the image again and delete the curved arrows in the centre. Set the colours of your quadrants how you want. Group the four quadrants again so you can select the whole as a single shape.
4. Insert a circle shape - this will probably default to blue. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click your quadrant shape and your new circle. On the Drawing Tools menu, use the Align tool to align middle, then align centre.

   [image]
5. Set the colour of your centre circle to white (both the fill and the border).

   [image]

Comment: Well written. Nice use of graphics to explain your answer.